# What part of Apache Commons saves you the most time?

Tags: java, apache-commons

Community wiki'ed already, folks.

**What part of Apache Commons saves you the most time?**

I'm curious to get together a list of these to browse and see what I don't know about, or what I should be using more often than not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

StringUtils.isBlank(String string)

Comment: ... which is equal to `"".equals(string.trim())`. BTW - it's part of commons-lang.

Comment: don't you need a not null test too?

Comment: @Andreas : more exactly, it tests if the string is null, empty, or full of whitespaces.

Comment: Because it takes SOOO much time to write a simple utility class that does the same thing without introducing a whole set of dependencies...

Comment: @GreenieMeanie yeah sure, like I only use this method from the whole commons-lang...Anyway, if it is in commons-lang already, YES, it is too much OF MY time to write something that does the same thing. Nevemind the dependency

Comment: @GreenieMeanie; arguably, you could rewrite all of J2EE with only the J2SE libraries, but that'd be dumb.  Commons are a single-layer deep of dependencies, so it's not any worse than any other library.

Comment: @raticulin, @Valentin - Ouch, you're right, if string is null, the string.trim() expression throws a NPE. Stupid mistake ;-) - yes, we need a null test, so it is: `(string == null || "".equals(string.trim()))`

Comment: @Andreas_D and that's why you'd use a library that already figured this out for you rather than trying to write your own implementation that may not work and also write unit tests to verify it. don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: And because of that, nobody can write an own library anymore - because nearly nobody really knows how "writing to a file" works without the library from apache. :(

Answer (score 5):

[commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)

Since StringUtils has got a lot of static methods, I like to use them using Expression Language [(EL)](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExpressionLanguageFAQ) in [seam](http://www.seamframework.org/), mapping StringUtils as a component

```
#{stringutils.left(r.map.job_error, 9)}
```

In components.xml:

```
<component name="stringutils" class="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils" scope="stateless"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

[commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) - the `Base64` and `Hex` classes at least.

Answer (score 4):

IOUtils, specifically FileUtils and IOUtils; it feels like the way that files + streams should have been done.  The repetitive work is handled for me, and the code is both quicker to write and clearer to read.

Comment: It's a bit too easy, though - ignoring IOExceptions thrown inside `closeQuietly` really isn't a good idea.

Comment: In some cases, if you know you'll do nothing about it anyway, ignoring them is a good way to go...

Comment: @skaffman: Ignoring the need for a second try/catch block to close the stream is where I love it.  Also, copying a file to a String becomes one method instead of a block of code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a huge fan of Apache Digester. I like persisting stuff to XML, and I love its rule based XML parser which just gives me the object without effort.

Answer (score 3):

[commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) is quite useful when writing configurable code.

Answer (score 2):

[FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) definitely. The remnant is either relatively easy to homegrow (which thus implies that it doesn't save that much time) or has better alternatives.

Comment: I don't really agree with the "easy to homegrow" point of view. You could easily hack together classes doing the same things, but why reinventing the wheel ? Generally, Apache Commons implementations are pretty simple, and well-tested.

Comment: @Valentin: I don't argue that and I wasn't insinuating that :) Truly, it's better to pick commons than reinventing the wheel, but the question literally states "Which saves you the most time?". Try reinventing FileUpload yourself without looking at its source/javadocs and tell how much time you wasted before getting it as rock solid as FileUpload.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayUtils: For my app development this helped the most.

Answer (score 1):

[DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html). It is so much simpler to use than Java's built in Date and Calendar classes. I don't know what I would do without it!

Comment: Have you tried http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ I find that the best Date utility library for Java.

Comment: I have tried it an it is also an excellent library. I find that I use DateUtil more because Apache Commons already included in the projects at work and usually covers the functionality that we need.

Comment: I believe apache's DateUtils and joda-time are both written by the same author (Stephen Colebourne)!

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons - provides various reusable components. I frequently use - Collections, IO, Digester, BeanUtils and EXEC.

Answer (score 0):

My vote goes to, `StringUtils` which is null safe...

There are some not always so common classes, but can save you time when the need raises:

```
RandomStringUtils (randomNumeric,randomAlphanumeric ...)
NumberUtils (toInt...)
```

Dig you can find good stuff there!